# Unit testing for Window Phone App

Tags: unit-testing, maven, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I am new to windows phone development and Visual Studio. I am writing a windows phone app on Visual Studio Express for Windows. This app has some WinRT components. To unit test this app I used Windows Phone Unit Test App. This Test app run on Windows phone. Is there anything for windows phone from which i can unit test the app apis on desktop itself if yes how can i achieve that?

Is there any maven plugin support for windows phone which does unit testing?

The basic idea behind this is to integrate it with Continuous integration server

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can put the API into a Portable Class Library and test this using other testing tools on your machine (in contrast to WP/Windows apps, xUnit and other great testing frameworks support PCLs)

Furthermore, for testing WP apps, you can do this on your machine as well by running them in the emulator.

To do all these things automatically, look into [mstest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) or even better: the new [vstest.console.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) which is used for app unit tests. Depending on what exactly you want to do, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073599/unit-testing-windows-store-app-msbuild-mstest-and-teamcity) or [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a4d2fca1-4034-4cc7-a86a-6242ce1a8b16/how-to-deploy-and-run-an-appx-from-c-code?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) might help :)

Comment: Thanks for the direction sibbl. I will check the option and let you know. 
Can I use cxxtest framework for creating unit testcases of Windows phone? In my previous project some guys where doing unit testing using cxxtest for a embedded project.

Comment: When i try to use  vstest.console.exe I am always getting
Warning: Unit tests for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps cannot be run outside appcontainer. Create an app package and run tests in appcontainer mode. [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254169] http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254169)


Warning: No test is available in UnitTestLibrary2.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Comment: And also which unit test project to create for creating unit test in command line? because when i try to list tests via vstest.console.exe it shows me a testcase name but when i try to run the dll it tells no testcase